# Decimal to hexadecimal conversion

Tags: ruby, string, hex

I have code as below:

```
x = readsomevalue();

print x
```

The printed value is an integer. I want this in hex but,

The integer which is returned(x) is having leading 0 in it(ex. 0543676). for this the standard method fails

x.to_s(16) = 0

how to solve this?
since some of you have marked it as duplicate let me tell you, that the standard call fails when we have leading 0 in it, so is there anything to eliminate leading 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fixnum#to_s`

```
255.to_s(16) # => "ff"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Kernel#format:`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format)

```
'%x' % 255 # => "ff"
```